# Financial dependency while over age of majority

Tags: india, family-law, children

If someone's father is not giving money to his child (21 years), can that child put a case on his father of not getting money for him as he is totally dependent on his father as that child is a student right now and not earning yet.

Comment: Can you rephrase this question? I cannot tell if you asking about child support payments or something else.

Comment: @Mr_Vitale Even if it was about child support, the child is above the age of majority, and is not dependent on the father

Comment: As Zizouz212 implied, generally no - particularly as if the kid is studying they are unlikely to be mentally impaired.  You should also advise what jurisdiction you are asking in when asking a question like this.

Comment: @Zizour212, I agree but some U.S. state courts have held that parents are for post-secondary school (college/trade school) educational expenses that are incurred after the age of majority, such as Connecticut & Iowa. See this website for a quick summary: http://www.ncsl.org/research/human-services/termination-of-support-college-support.aspx.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad since no information is given: information such as nature of the dependency, jurisdiction, among other things that are necessary to make a suitable answer.

Comment: @RhythmMurgai Where is this, please?  If it's the US, which state?  Are there any other factors such as a physical or mental disability?  I will join Zizouz212's vote but reverse if these questions are answered in a clarification.

Comment: living in india

Comment: @RhythmMurgai Is the child pretty much a regular student, or are there other abnormal conditions?

Comment: @WBT yes he is a regular student and wants to fulfill his desires.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **no** (or at least, very probably not successfully).
The "child" is over the age of majority (for most jurisdictions anyway) and remaining a student is not enough to create a legal financial dependency.

In India, the [age of majority is generally 18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority_Act_%28India%29) but is [different for certain circumstances](http://infochangeindia.org/agenda/child-rights-in-india/who-is-a-child.html).
As discussed [here](http://infochangeindia.org/agenda/child-rights-in-india/who-is-a-child.html),

> Unless a particular personal law specifies otherwise, every person domiciled in India is deemed to have attained majority upon completion of 18 years of age. However, in the case of a minor for whose person or property, or both, a guardian has been appointed or declared by any court of justice before the age of 18 years, and in case of every minor the superintendence of whose property has been assumed by the Court of Wards, age of majority will be 21 years and not 18.

So even if the child had fallen into this category, once they reach 21 they have passed the age of majority.

For those in the US, Mr_Vitale has [pointed out](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/11966/financial-dependency-while-over-age-of-majority/11967#comment21630_11966) the distinction between child support and [college support](http://www.ncsl.org/research/human-services/termination-of-support-college-support.aspx), which may exist in your state; check the [link](http://www.ncsl.org/research/human-services/termination-of-support-college-support.aspx) for state-specific details.